# Could any new structures be formed after the heat death of the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, universe, hawking-radiation

When the universe would reach a maximal state of entropy, heat death would presumably be reached and no structures would be left after the last black hole would evaporate.

However, is this really true? Is it impossible then for new structures to form? Couldn't there be any formation of new structures (like black holes) in the future?

I'm asking this after reading section F.1. of this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131) which says that there would be a continuous formation and evaporation of black holes as the universe ages due to density perturbations. So, could this be possible?

Comment: have a look https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe#Future

Answer (score 1):

In a static (in terms of cosmological expansion or contraction) universe, and if black holes evaporate (which I think they likely do), Poincare recursion  theorem guarantees that any structure will eventually form again by random chance. Entropy fluctuates, the larger the fluctuation the longer it takes to see it happen. In our expanding universe this does not seem to be the case, for instance, you could have the big rip. No structure like the ones existing today could possibly form in such a case, and the universe eventually becomes causally disconnected.

Comment: Your answer seems to be based on the false idea that the universe expands with acceleration. This hoax has been debunked long ago, but the establishment still milks this idea. There is no acceleration, no Big Rip, no causal disconnection (at the very least within a galaxy).

Comment: @safesphere as far as I know the universe expansion is accelerating, do you have any actual proof of what you are saying is true?

Comment: @PatoGalmarini why would no structures form in such case?

Comment: I am not talking about any hoax, but rather about the assumptions. if the universe is static and close the theorem is guaranteed, if not, we don't know, you could try proving  it for the universe of your choice.

Comment: @safesphere please read what I wrote, I only put it as possible scenario in which structures will not form. I never claimed that big rip is going to happen.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini Then, on the last line, you should replace “becomes” with “could become” or “would become”.

Comment: @vengaq I replied, but my comment silently disappeared. Apparently truth is too inconvenient on this site. So do your own research. For example, this is only a tip of the iceberg: https://newatlas.com/universe-expansion-not-accelerating/46078/

Comment: Poincare theorem holds under some assumptions, one of which is finite phase space.